# Enable button on callback if recaptcha successful (Google recaptcha v2)

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, recaptcha

I have a simple page that has a button with a link variable linked to it, I want to add a recaptcha validation to the page, in a way where the button will be only visible if the recaptcha is validated

```html
<a id="cl-link" class="cl-link-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>" rel="nofollow"><span></span></a>
```

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='link-single'  href='<?php echo DOO_URI,'/css/cl.css'; ?>' type='text/css' media='all' />
    </head>
    <body>  
 
 
    <a id="cl-link" class="cl-link-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>" rel="nofollow"><span></span></a>


 
 
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you using reCaptcha. can you write a sample?

Comment: I've just added the full code, I don't use it, I just want to add it to avoid bad clicks on link (id="cl-link")

Answer (score 1):

If you use Javascript to render the Recaptcha component, a function is fired after Recaptcha has been successfully verified.

So, for Recaptcha v3:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         $("#cl-link").show();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Or, if you are using Recaptcha v2 and html, there is an attribute `data-callback` to add a callback function to the component.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptcha_callback" data-sitekey="xxxxx"></div>
```

In your Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recaptcha_callback(){
      $('#cl-link').show();
    }
</script>
```

I have assumed that you have JQuery in your web page for displaying the button.  If not, you should use native Javascript to show the button.

Comment: No, am not using javascript am using html and php

Comment: sadly, it did not work, the button still showing up and when I check the recaptcha nothing happens

Comment: I can't see the DIV for Recaptcha in your HTML.  How are you rendering Recaptcha?

Comment: I just implemented the recaptcha v2 as you said up there